# Confused on proof questions about relations

Tags: proof-writing, relations

Prove or disprove: Let 1 and 2 be relations on a set .

a) If 1 and 2 are reflexive relations, then 1 ∪ 2 is reflexive.

b) If 1 and 2 are symmetric relations, then 1 ∪ 2 is symmetric.

c) If 1 and 2 are transitive relations, then 1 ∪ 2 is transitive.

So my confusion stems from the fact that, doesn't R1 U R2 mean R1 or R2? So if they are both reflexive and then it says to prove if one or the other is reflexive then isn't it a given?

Could someone also maybe help solve one part to guide me on solving the rest? Thanks

Comment: You can think of a relation on $A$ as a collection of subsets of $A\times A$  (where $(a_1,a_2)$ is in the collection iff $a_1\sim a_2$).  A union of two relations is then the union of all those subsets.

Comment: To prove that the union is symmetric, note that if $(a,b)$ is in the union then we must either have $a\sim_1 b$ or $a\sim_2 b$.  But if $a\sim_1b$ then $b\sim_1 a$ since $R_1$ is symmetric and similarly for $R_2$ so either way we must also have $(b,a)$ in the union.  The transitive question is a bit trickier but shoiuld be approached in the same way.